# New MicroSd card readonly/"Windows cannot read disk"

Tags: windows, micro-sd-card

I got a few brand new 32GB micro-SD cards with included adaptors. I then tried moving some data to it, but there was a problem, so I tried removing the write-only properties so i could complete the move. I have tried two of them, and when I did it with a CMD script, it made my micro-SD card unreadable - `Windows cannot access this disk`. It is currently in read-only mode. It had nothing stored on it. I'm worried it's faulty forever at this point, I cannot find any help online.

Comment: I tried moving storage from a 4gb sd card to the 32gb micro sd.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the physical "Lock ON/OFF" switch on SD-card is not locked

Comment: Micro-SD cards don't have a lock switch.